# Authorization Failure with Google Map API key

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, android-maps-v2

I am building a project for android 4.3 and building to an actual device but my google map always shows up empty and i get an authorization failure..  But everything checks out..

I have a network connection..

**LOG ERROR**
[image]

**GOOGLE API CONSOLE**
[image]

**SERVICES IN CONSOLE**
[image]

**My Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sapientnitro.inhouse.drop"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.sapientnitro.inhouse.drop.activities.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.sapientnitro.inhouse.drop.activities.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
         <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>


        <activity
            android:name=".activities.DRPSplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.DRPMapViewActivity"
            android:launchMode="standard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyA7tcgqzYWAcqLd0ea5qAqHYpaYKTHQv5s" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: since you are using v2 this `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>` is not needed

Comment: yeah, i know, i added that because i was at my wits end.. but that shouldn't effect the authorization

Answer (score 5):

problem solved..  i had to uninstall the app, and do a project clean, then re-install the app.. don't know why exactly but now its working

Comment: Anecdotally, this works in reverse too. That is, install with a good API key, swap it out for a bad one, and the 'good' value stays cached until uninstall.

Comment: @erik: thanks, i also had the same problem, unistallation fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Your API key in your manifest clearly does not match the API key you posted that is showing in the API console. Paste the API key from the console into the manifest. Should fix you right up.